# Can jsoup handle huge html file of size around 1GB

Tags: java, jsoup

What is max size of html String can  jsoup handle ? I have html string which need to be parsed, html string can be very huge around 500MB.  Can jsoup handle it?

Comment: Why would you ever have an HTML file that big? Do you have any idea how much information that is?

Comment: Have you considered how long it would take to download a 500MB HTML string?

Comment: i also have a similar case. im my case the xml file size is 50GB. It's a dump of a english wiki data(enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml). i hope to use jsoup to parse it.

Answer (score 1):

If you increase the memory of your VM it *should* work; use `-Xms<n>` and `-Xmx<n>` options for this (where `<n>` is memory size).

eg. `java -Xms500m -Xmx600m ...`

possible you have to *fine tune* these values; you also can use a profiler to check how much memory is used.

See also: [java - the Java application launcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html)